# Why Keras preprocess_input() switch RGB to BGR

Tags: tensorflow, keras

[Documentaion for preprocess_input](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/resnet/preprocess_input).

It is mentioned in that

Returns
Preprocessed numpy.array or a tf.Tensor with type float32.
The images are converted from **RGB** to **BGR**, then each color channel is zero-centered with respect to the ImageNet dataset, without scaling.

Why need to convert **RGB** to **BGR**? what is the reason behind?

Answer (score 1):

In the function [preprocess_input](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L104) the default mode used is [Caffe](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L169) which seems to be the only option that you can process images in when using `preprocess_input()` based on this [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L169).

`Caffe` uses `OpenCV` for many image operations, and `OpenCV` defaults to reading images into `BGR`.

Comment: How do we know which pretrained keras models were trained in caffe mode, or in normal RGB mode?